# Datepicker bootstrap default date

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I am currently trying to set the default date for my datepicker. When I use set the defaultDate variable, all this seems to do is populate the date input field. Is there any way I can set the default date so it does not populate the input field, however it will show the default date when you open up the dialog box?

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  viewMode: "years",
  viewDate: '06/06/1987',
  minDate: "01/01/1900",
  defaultDate: "06/06/1950",
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this:

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  viewMode: "years",
  viewDate: moment('1987-06-06'), // Use moment objects.
  minDate: moment("1900-01-01"),
  defaultDate: moment("1950-06-06")
});
$('.datepicker').val("");   // Empty the input field on load.
```

See in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/VbNepz).

Answer (score 0):

Before initializing the `datetimepicker` set the default date in the input field data.

```
var defaultDate = new Date("1950-06-06");
$('.datepicker').data("date", defaultDate);
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  viewMode: "years",
  viewDate: '06/06/1987',
  minDate: "01/01/1900"
});
```